# Finding out if cells in a data frame column contain a specific character in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, grepl

I want to find out if cells in a data frame column contain a specific character in R.

I created a column called `df1$var_sting` using the code below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  var_sting = 
    c(
    "test1",
    "test2 + test3"
    )
  )
```

I want to create a column called `df1$plus_test_short`, which contains a `"yes/no"` answer to the question on whether a character ("+") is present in the variable called "df1$var_sting".

I can do this the long way, using the code below:

```
df1$plus_test_long <- 
  c(
    "no",
    "yes"
  )
```

When I try to do this the short way, using the `grepl()` command, it does not give the desired result:

```
> df1$plus_test_short
[1] "yes" "yes"
```

Is there any way to do this using a short way, that does not require me to input results individually in the `plus_test_` prefixed columns that correspond to the appropriate rows in the `df1$var_sting` variable?

Please advise. Thanks a head of time.

---

---

```
# stackoverflow example data

## creates object
df1 <- data.frame(
  var_sting = 
    c(
    "test1",
    "test2 + test3"
    )
  )

### displays object
df1

## desired new column, which tells if there is a + (plus sign) in the cell

### done the long way, which requires manual input
df1$plus_test_long <- 
  c(
    "no",
    "yes"
  )

## done the short way, using grepl() command, which does not require manual entering of "yes" and "no" with each cell in corresponding column
df1$plus_test_short <- 
  ifelse(((grepl("+", df1$var_sting)) == TRUE), "yes", "no")
df1$plus_test_short
# ---- NOTE: does not work
```

---

---

Comment: Your `grepl` version at the end is completely correct _except_ that you need to escape the `+`, i.e. use `ifelse(grepl("\\+", df1$var_sting), "yes", "no")`

Comment: Voting to close as being caused by a typo.

Comment: Or use `grepl("+", df1$var_sting, fixed=TRUE)`